# Extract CMake commandline from cmake-gui output

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I am using a thirdparty library that is using CMake. This library is highly configurable. For the projects I am using this library I tend to create a specific configuration of this library (its an embedded use-case). Being lazy I use the cmake-gui for this.

This works fine, but now I also want to be able to write a README.md for my colleagues containing a cmake commandline with the exact configuration of that thirdparty library required (aka. cmake -DSOMETHING=OFF -D...

How do I extract this information from the cmake-gui output? Preferably in an automated fashion.

Comment: Specifically, I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49987399/3987854) might be the closest available feature to what you're looking for.